# Custom JSP Tag processor is caching a dated property, so the page shows old data and don't update, how to avoid this?

Tags: java, jsp-tags, custom-tag, object-pooling

I made a **custom jsp tag** that **search a historical value** on a database an render it on the page. The **attributes** that the tag requires are the **variable name** and the **date**.

The **problem** is that the '**date**' property **changes** according clock move on ('date' points always to the last hour), **but** the JSP Tag processor's (**jasper2**) pooling system **don't update** the '**date**' property anymore (calling to the **setDate**), and the page **stays freezed** on a point in time.

I don't want to disable the pooling system because it gives performance to the web, but i need to tell it somehow that '**date**' property must be setted always.

There is a trick o a procedure to force this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you please add some code to make it clearer?

Comment: it's solved. I'd invented a conspiracy theory about Jasper2 and pooling strategies against me, but the problem was me: I didn't respect the directive that says that i don't have to change the 'date' property internally. Thanks and sorry for stealing your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what pooling you are talking about.

Part of the JSP specification that all containers implement is the distinction between attributes evaluated at runtime and those evaluated when the page is compiled.

In the TLD, you must declare the `date` attribute's `<rtexprvalue/>` to be `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the problem: Me. I didn't respect the directive that says that i don't have to change the 'date' property internally. Thanks and sorry for stealing your time.